# Uninstantiated Anonymous Classes in Java

Tags: java, anonymous-class

It's been about 6 years since I've written Java, so please excuse the rust.

I'm working with a library method that requires that I pass it `Class` objects.  Since I'll have to invoke this method a dynamic number of times, each time with a slightly different `Class` argument, I wanted to pass it an anonymous class.

However, all the documentation/tutorials I've been able to find so far only talk about instantiating anonymous classes, [e.g.](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3300881):

```
new className(optional argument list){classBody}

new interfaceName(){classBody}
```

Can I define an anonymous class without instantiating it?  Or, perhaps more clearly, can I create a `Class` object for an anonymous class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way you can dodge the instantiation here. You can make it a no-op, however:

```
foo((new Object() { ... }).getClass());
```

Of course, this might not be an option if you have to derive from some class that performs some actions in constructor.

#### EDIT

Your question also says that you want to call `foo` "each time with a slightly different Class argument". The above won't do it, because there will still be a single anonymous inner class *definition*, even if you put the new-expression in a loop. So it's not really going to buy you anything compared to named class definition. In particular, if you're trying to do it to capture values of some local variables, the new instance of your anonymous class that `foo` will create using the `Class` object passed to it *will not* have them captured.

Comment: Thanks for the details in the EDIT.  Could I pass it a member inner class instead, and have that member inner class refer to some instance variable of the parent class?  I'm not sure whether member inner classes can be passed.  I guess I could always fall back on a regular class with some static parameters that I can modify between calls.

Comment: No. You cannot "create classes at runtime", so to speak. Variable capture (including capture of `this`) works on instance level, not on class level. What it in fact does is just add a few hidden parameters to constructor of your inner class, and pass the values in them. Obviously that only works when you create the instance right there and let compiler do its magic.

Answer (score 1):

### short answer

you cannot (using only JDK classes)

### long answer

give it a try:

```
public interface Constant {

    int value();
}

public static Class<? extends Constant> classBuilder(final int value) {
    return new Constant() {

        @Override
        public int value() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }.getClass();
}
```

let's creating two new class "parametric" classes:

```
Class<? extends Constant> oneClass = createConstantClass(1);
Class<? extends Constant> twoClass = createConstantClass(2);
```

however you cannot instantiate this classes:

```
Constant one = oneClass.newInstance(); // <--- throws InstantiationException
Constant two = twoClass.newInstance(); // <--- ditto
```

it will fail at runtime since **there is only one instance for every anonymous class**.

However you can build *dynamic classes* at runtime using **bytecode manipulation libraries such [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)**. Another approach is using [dynamic proxies](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but this approach as the drawback that you can proxy only interface methods (so you need a Java interface).

Comment: -1 "it will fail at runtime since there is only one instance for every anonymous class" This isn't true - anonymous classes can have many instances. The `InstantiationException` is being thrown because the anonymous class in your example closes over `value`, so behind the scenes its constructor takes a single `int` argument (removing the implicit public default constructor). Looking up that `Constructor` using reflection allows you to instantiate the anon class successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reference an anonymous class ONCE.  If you do not instantiate it there, you cannot instantiate it since you do not have a name for it.

Hence I believe that anonymous classes can only be used in conjunction with a "new BaseClass()".

In your situation you would pass a BaseClass object to your method doing the work, and instantiate the anonymous object in the source code when you need the object to pass.

Comment: It's not my method, it's a library I'm using.  It needs the `Class` because it creates more than one instantiation.  So passing it an instance won't work.

Comment: Then anonymous classes will not work.  Perhaps nested classes instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the Class object of an anonymous class without instatiating it. However, if you only need access to the class, you could define local classes within your method and  refer to these using the ClassName.class literal syntax.

Comment: Although this probably won't help you if you're trying to capture local variables because I don't think the method you are passing it to will be able to instatiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume the name of an anonymous class and call `Class.forName("mypackage.MyBaseClass$1")` to get a handle to an anonymous class. This will give you the first anonymous class defined in your `MyBaseClass`, so this is a rather fragile way to refer to a class.

I suspect whatever you are trying to do could be done a better way. What are you really trying to achieve? Perhaps we can suggest a way which doesn't require you to pass a `Class` this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the class object of an anonymous class by calling `.getClass()` on it immediately after creation. But what good would that do?

I think the key is in this part of what you said:

> I'm working with a library method that requires that I pass it Class
>   objects.

*Why* does it want you to pass it Class objects? What does this library do with the Class objects you pass it? Instantiate objects? But if so, what constructor does it use and how does it decide what arguments to pass? I don't know what library you are using or what it does, but I would guess that it always creates objects using the no-argument constructor. However, that will not work for anonymous classes anyway, since they have no public constructor (and in any case, to instantiate any non-static inner class, a reference to the outer instance must be provided, so there is no no-argument constructor).